# JQuery How to get the file name

Tags: jquery, file

I was trying to get the exact name of the uploaded file I tried this code but whenever I upload a file it only `alert` the file type.

for example I upload `banner.jpg` then it `prompt` the `"jpg"`... what is I  am trying to do is I want to `alert` the name of the file the `"banner"` only.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#s").click(function(){
    alert($('#myfile').val().split('.').pop());
});
});

<p id='s'>Click me too!</p>
<input type="file" id="myfile">
```

Comment: you might not be able to get that information.

Comment: You could start with `alert($('#myfile').val().split('.').shift());`

Comment: Hi felix, can you please move your comment into answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just peeked what `event` of `input type=file` contains and found where it holds file names.

```
$('#yourSelector').on("change",function(e){
    console.log(e.target.files[0].name);
});
```

tested chrome41,safari8 on yosemite

and ofc You can do this too.

```
$("#yourSelector").val().split('/').pop().split('\\').pop();
```